# How can I refer to the columns of a table after I used INNER JOIN in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I asked this question once before but it got deleted because it was unnecessarily long, so I deleted it, edited it so that it would be shorter and to the point and reposted here:

I have the following tables in a MySQL database that are represented in the following image:[image]

I want to get the fields `id`, `id_user`, `body` and `post_date` from all the `posts` with one or more specific tags that where originaly in the table `posts`. To achieve that I try to `INNER JOIN`
`posts` to `posts_has_tags` to `tags` and get the `posts.id`, `posts.id_user`, `posts.body`, `posts.post_date` but I get the following error:

```
Unknown column 'posts.id' in 'field list'
```

The query I use to INNER JOIN is the following:

```
SELECT posts.id AS post_id, id_user, body , post_date
                  FROM posts INNNER JOIN posts_has_tags
                  ON post_id = posts_id
                  INNER JOIN tags
                  ON tags.id = tags_id
```

Why is `posts.id` raising an error? Is it beacause I have `INNER JOINED` the tables and if so what can I do to fix it?

P.S. I know that I didn't post the `WHERE` statement in the query but the problem is not there so I left it out.

Comment: You can’t joint using an alias. Use posts.id in join.

Comment: I tried with and without the alias so I don't think that this is the only problem. Thanks for poining out thought @P.Salmon

Comment: `INNNER JOIN posts_has_tags` "iNNNer" is misspelled and believe it or not that error message caused by that misspelling. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a1f8a6b9eec4c2f193b413008666a242

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are dealing with multiple tables in a query preface each column references with the table that supplies that column. e.g.:

```
SELECT
    posts.id AS post_id ## nb this is a "column alias"
  , posts.id_user
  , posts.body
  , posts.post_date
FROM posts 
INNER JOIN posts_has_tags ON posts.id = posts_has_tags.posts_id
INNER JOIN tags           ON posts_has_tags.tags_id = tags.id
```

OR, to make this somewhat easier to prepare you can declare table aliases, then preface each column reference with the relevant alias instead, e.g.:

```
SELECT
    p.id AS post_id
  , p.id_user
  , p.body
  , p.post_date
FROM posts AS p  ## nb this is a "table alias"
INNER JOIN posts_has_tags AS pt ON p.id = pt.posts_id
INNER JOIN tags AS t            ON pt.tags_id = t.id
```

Whilst you can take the risk that a specific colum_name may be unique with a set of joined tables, this may not always be true if someone alters a table, so it is "good practice" (in my view) to always preface a column with its table or alias.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=223e1f48e64513a375146ca2e8a71343

Note: you alias posts.id as post_id, but that column name already exists in posts_has_tags. This "mixing-up" of columns names is a small example of why it is risky omit table/alias references when writing queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t join using an alias. Use posts.id in join and correct the typo INNNER JOIN
and the query syntaxes.

```
SELECT posts.id AS post_id, id_user, body , post_date
FROM posts 
INNER JOIN posts_has_tags   ON posts.id = posts_id
INNER JOIN tags             ON tags.id = tags_id;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e0cba7e787fa1ab61a926a38b7e98e02